# Не удалился constraint на базе Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Использую oracle 11g базу.
В прошлом, на таблицу представленную ниже под названием User, накатили скрипт ограничения уникальность для полей name и surname(constraint)

Таблица User:
    id     name    surname     age    position

Создание ограничения constraint:

```
alter table User add constraint UK8ut91db3xdtls2x61e63iwym4 unique (name, surname);
```

Сейчас пришла необходимость избавиться от этого ограничения.
Удалил ограничение с таблицы скриптом:

```
  alter table ORGANIZATION.USER drop constraint UK8UT91DB3XDTLS2X61E63IWYM4
```

И причем это ограничение вроде как удалилось, попытка найти его селектом - ничего не вернулся, до этого селект его находил:

```
SELECT * FROM all_constraints WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME='UK8UT91DB3XDTLS2X61E63IWYM4'
```

last script returns nothing.

Но, при попытке записать две строки, с разными id, но с совпадающими именем и фамилией, я получаю ошибку

```
INSERT INTO ORGANIZATION.USER(id, name, surname, age, position) VALUES (111-222, 'Natalia', 'Solzhenizina', 22, 'consultant')
Error report -
ORA-00001: нарушено ограничение уникальности  (constraint violetion on unique) (ORGANIZATION.UK8UT91DB3XDTLS2X61E63IWYM4)
```

Я слышал, что Oracle не всегда удаляет по факту эти constraint. Как выйти из этого положения, когда ограничения уникальности нужно исключить?

Comment: Что возвращает: `select * from all_objects where object_name='UK8UT91DB3XDTLS2X61E63IWYM4';` ?

Comment: Интересно, а в какой схеме это происходит. Таблица вроде как  ORGANIZATION.USER, а вот почему у вас констраинт в другой схеме (SBDATASVCS.UK8UT91DB3XDTLS2X61E63IWYM4), это интересный вопрос

Comment: @Mike Опечатался - исправил

Comment: Интересно как вы так опечатлись. Сообщение об ошибке обычно копируют ... А то я было подумал что вы ограничение на другой схеме создали вот и не видите его в текущем

Comment: @Mike не везде подменил название проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, правильно удалять нужно так: (указав Cascad)

```
alter table ORGANIZATION.USER drop constraint UK8UT91DB3XDTLS2X61E63IWYM4 CASCADE
```

Если этого не сделать, то останутся другие элементы constraint, такие как ограничения и индекс(uniques и index)

Если уж произошло удаление без Cascade, то можно зачистить индекс и уникальность руками так:

```
DROP INDEX ORGANIZATION.UK8UT91DB3XDTLS2X61E63IWYM4

alter table ORGANIZATION.USER drop UNIQUE (name, surname);
```